# View controller is obscured when pushing a navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, layout, viewcontroller

I have a navigation controller and a view controller inside of the navigation controller. 
The view controller calls the navigation controller to push a view:

```
    `MYVC *myvc = [MYVC new]`;
    `[self.navigationController pushViewController:myvc
                                         animated:YES]`;
```

Inside of `MYVC` I have the following logic for laying out my collection view:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
     [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

_collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 
                                   0,
                                   self.view.frame.size.width,
                                   self.view.frame.size.height - height);
}
```

This works fine for when I first load my vc as the collection view is loaded under my nav bar. 
However when I push my vc it looks like the following: 
[image: Collection View]

[image: Overlap]

Above the divider line is my nav bar and the red is my colleciton view. 
It looks like the collection view is laid out under my navigation bar. If I drag on my collection view it lays out properly. 
If I try changing the `_collectionView` frame's y position to 
`self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height` however I get a large whitespace above my collection view after I drag on my collection view. How can I get it to be laid out properly the first time? Do I have to force layout? Is there some reason my nav bar isn't taken into account for the vc until I drag in the scroll view?

Comment: It seems to me that the issue might be related to the fact that the view controller is actually *under* the navigation bar. I'm not push why that would be the case as the view controller is inited in the navigation bar.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas or can point me to a similar case where this happens? I haven't found anything on SO